# openlayers 6 map getview fit zooms out on every refresh

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Im using openlayers 6, on mounted I use map().getView().fit(extent)
for some reason on every refresh the zoom level is higher.
any tips how to fix this?

Before using .fit(extent) I have to transformExtent to change projection from 5514 to 3857

```
this.map().setView(new View({
  projection: 'EPSG:3857',
  center: fromLonLat([50.075710, 14.472606]),
  zoom: 10,
  enableRotation: false
}))
extent = transformExtent(extent, 'EPSG:5514', this.map().getView().getProjection().getCode())
this.map().getView().fit(extent)
```

before refresh:
[image]

after refresh:
[image]

my problem is with map.getview.fit
here is my code and here are the returned values
coordinates after view.fit are a bit different

```
  console.log(transformedExtent)
  this.map().getView().fit(transformedExtent, this.map().getSize())
  console.log(this.map().getView().calculateExtent(this.map().getSize()))
```

before fit:

1. -27186.072153485078
2. 6701982.491006854
3. -5136.804165771885
4. 6724373.669054876

after fit:

1. -27186.072153485078
2. 6701493.775314425
3. -5136.804165771886
4. 6724862.384747305

Answer (score 1):

Asked about this problem directly on openlayers github and it is expected behavior.
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/13503

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable for the EPSG:5514 and EPSG:3857 extents so presumably corrupting the original EPSG:5514 you want to use. Using a separate variable should solve the problem.

```
const transformedExtent = transformExtent(extent, 'EPSG:5514', this.map().getView().getProjection().getCode())
this.map().getView().fit(transformedExtent)
```

Comment: tried using separate variable as you mentioned, but the same problem still occurs

Comment: it changes the bbox size by itself after refresh
example:
before refresh: bbox=-1703174.5495622233,-648992.7960325009,-1703065.1744425278,-648879.8901709078
after refresh:
bbox=-1703211.108541262,-649030.528473364,-1703028.6233287624,-648842.1524496544